# How to integrate KeyCloak with WSo2 Identity Server? WSo2 IS as IDP

Tags: keycloak, wso2-identity-server

I have requirement to integrate WSo2 IS with Keycloak.
Where from Keycloak I should be able to authentication the users present in WSo2 IS.

Comment: The question it too broad

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the guide in [Configure WSO2 Identity Server as a Federated IDP in Keycloak](https://medium.com/@anuradha.15/integrate-wso2-identity-server-as-an-oidc-idp-with-keycloak-276e6f52357b), to configure WSO2 IS as an OIDC IDP in Keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Identity Brokering](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker). WSo2 IS will be identity provider.

Comment: Is there any document to make WSo2 IS to make Identity provider?

Comment: @sureshkumar I don't know. You said that in the title `WSo2 IS as IDP`